# Entity framework code first relationship issue in a normalized schema

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Its a simple question.

I have designed a project with a normalized database schema.

I am using code first.

I have a table called JOBS. I have another table called status. I intend to give a job a status. The status has to be user set so its in a table which you can add to. A job can be, say, "booked", "parts to be ordered", "invoiced". etc

As a POCO class I have the table STATUS with the following:

> statusID  (PK)
>
> statusName
>
> description.

In the JOBS table I would have a column called statusID as the foreign, non null key. EG

> jobsID    (PK)
>
> clientID  (FK)
>
> statusID  (FK)
>
> jobTypeID (FK)

.
.

My question is, can I do this? Can I have a number of statelite tables (client, status, jobType) with names and descriptions and in the JOBS table there is a column with the satelite tables primary key as the column name?

I am confused as to what relationship this represents (one to one - one to many) and whether you can use the primary key of one table as the foreign key in the JOBS table when approaching this using Code First. Its not overly clear in the tutorials I have worked through.

Bottom line I want a specific job and be able to attach a specific status to it and in the view show the job with that status name and description...

Hoping someone might clear up the mud..

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do are simple one-to-many relationships.
You have already defined this and everything looks fine for me.

But you can also add the Navigation property to your status class to make this one-to-**many** relationship more clear:

```
public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
```